# Не могу переписать XOR с C на Java

Tags: java, c

Здравствуйте, переписываю XOR с языка C на Java

C:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const uint8_t KEY [] = {23,45,67,84,34,32,56,78,45,67,89,23,45,67,89,34,5,6,45,34,35,0};
int main(int ac, char **av) {
if(ac > 0) {
    printf("{");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(av[1]);i++) {
        if(KEY[j] == 0) j = 0;
        char c = av[1][i] ^ KEY[j++];
        printf("0x%02X,",c);
    }
    printf("0}\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Запутался, как сделать аналогию в строчке

```
char c = av[1][av] ^ KEY[j++];
```

На данный момент на Java код такой:

```
public class Main {

private static char[] KEY = {23,45,67,84,34,32,56,78,45,67,89,23,45,67,89,34,5,6,45,34,35,0};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Input: ");
    String text = new Scanner(System.in).next();
    System.out.print("{");
    int j = 0;
    for (char textChar : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (KEY[j] == 0) j = 0;
        char c = textChar ^ KEY[j++];
        System.out.print(String.format("0x%02X,", c));
    }
    System.out.print("0}\n");
}
}
```

Comment: там просто выражение `textChar ^ KEY[j++]` надо привести к `char`, потому что оно int возвращает

Comment: @Komdosh, спасибо, но теперь я получаю `IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.Character` в строчке где `String.format`. Так и думал, что неверно. Как в Java такое сделать?

Comment: а там надо подогнать размер c & 0xFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операция `XOR` присутствует в `Java` и обозначается точно также как и в Си `^`, оно вернёт `int`, а его необходимо приводить к `char` в отличии от Си. Для вывода значения в `String.format` необходимо подогнать размер выводимого значения.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Input: ");
    String text = new Scanner(System.in).next();
    System.out.print("{");
    int j = 0;
    for (char textChar : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (KEY[j] == 0) j = 0;
        int c = textChar ^ KEY[j++];
        System.out.print(String.format("0x%02X,", c & 0xFF));
    }
    System.out.print("0}\n");
}
```